# Homeomorphisms on Zariski topologies

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I'm looking for a continuous bijection from a compact space to a non-Hausdorff topological space which isn't a homeomorphism. Since the identity $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z},\ x\rightarrow x$ is bijective and any regular map of varieties is continuous in the Zariski topology, could this be a candidate?

Comment: Why not simply use $x\mapsto x$ from $\{0,1\}$ under the the discrete topology to the same set under the indiscrete topology?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I was explicitly looking for an example using Zariski.

Comment: Then you should be more specific as to which topology you wanted to use on which copy of $\mathbb Z$, I suppose.

Comment: What is your definition of compact? Do you require a compact space to be Hausdorff?

Comment: Compact in the sense of quasi-compact. So no, it doesn't need to be Hausdorff.